# Getting list of items through share point web service

Tags: sharepoint

I want to get a list of documents which are in `Shared Documents` (this is the `Document Library`). I am using the `GetListItems` web service.

I am getting response with list of rows. But I don't see a word document which is created under that. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GetListItems method does not return actual documents, it returns the ListItem information  (metadata). It should include a Url (FileRef / FileLeafRef) property you can use to download the documents by looping through the method's result.

Comment: Yes, 'GetListItems' returns only List Item information. But I am unable to see "document url" of a document which is created by me. It returns me some rows but I don't find my document in that.
I have given query options as below with listName as guid of "Shared Documents"
<QueryOptions>
  <Folder></Folder>
  <IncludeMandatoryColumns>FALSE</IncludeMandatoryColumns>
  <ViewAttributes Scope="Recursive"/>
<IncludeAttachmentUrls>TRUE</IncludeAttachmentUrls>
</QueryOptions>

Comment: Include a ViewFields section in your xml, use FieldRef elements inside that to specify which fields should be returned by the query.

Comment: I am able to read list items successfully. I made a mistake in Gateway URL, which was point to root URL instead of the one which I have permission.